# How do I configure a custom security domain so that it doesn't need to be specified when logging in?

Tags: security

I have a custom security domain that has a majority of content authors in it.  I feel like, there is a way, so that rather than optionally having to type in `sitecore\user`, you can make your custom security domain optional to enter.

So rather than having to type `my-custom-domain\user`, you can just type in user (like you can with any user in the Sitecore security domain).

If anyone can remind me, how to configure this, I would really appreciate it.  My recollection is that, you can only have one security domain that is optional to enter, so a consequence would be that any Sitecore security domain users would need to enter in `sitecore\user` to login, which is fine.

Comment: Once we started using the switcher provider, we had to provide the domain name for our custom domain. Perhaps it has to do with the order of the configured providers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the `domain` attribute of the `login` site node in configuration, by default it is **"sitecore"**:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="login" set:domain="powerful" />
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

As you say, you can only have a single default domain, if you change this then users in the `sitecore\` domain will need to explicitly specify it.